# Bottom border of bootstrap column goes outside of column because of negative margin of row and padding of column

Tags: css

I am trying to add a bottom border to a bootstrap column, but it's going outside the column div because of the negative margin of row and bootstrap column's padding. Please see below:

[image]

Is there any way I can prevent border from going outside and show up only within the column content, like below?

[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 add-border">
      A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion its better to leave default TB grid styles as it is. You can achieve this with one excess wrap i.e. `<div class="col-md-12"><div class="add-border">A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div></div>`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman That's actually a very good and the ideal way I think. This would prevent the unnecessary modification of bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply padding:0 to your the divs you want to have the border (the following assumes a 3px border-width - change it to suit):

```
.add-border{
  padding:0;
  border-bottom:3px solid #000;
 }
```

if you only want to affect the padding to the left and right (but not the top and bottom) then you can use the following:

```
.add-border{
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
  border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Why you use semicolon at the end?

Comment: sorry - force of habit - answer amended

Answer (score 0):

Try this and set border using `after` pseudo element.

```
.add-border:after {
  content:'';
  width:270px;
  height:5px;
  background:black;
  position:absolute;
  left:13px;
  top:24px;
}
```

Comment: I think applying padding:0 to the divs where border is desired is the simpler solution as @gavgrif suggested.

Comment: @Rishabh Yes it will, you could try both solution. I thought you need to optimize your border, if so try this. And yes padding:0 set's it's position to 0 but still border-bottom is covering full-page on x-axis.